# Lost Auth when changing Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 8 when I use
login path for force login,

```
Route::get('/login',function (){
   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::loginUsingId(1); 
return dd(Auth::check()); // <--- true, so is ok.
});
```

and then check if I am logged it return null

```
Route::get('/test_login',function (){
return dd(Auth::check()); // <-- here is false
```

What's append?

Comment: Are these web routes or api routes? Also check if sessions are working properly

Comment: this are web routes, I've added ->middleware('web') in both routes, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session and make sure your sessions are configured correctly and are working

Comment: Please can you add your entire routes file.

Comment: yes, this is my web.php routes: https://pastebin.com/LKfr5EWQ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make sure that your column name of user table is `id`, if not you can change it in the User class by adding

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_current_name_for_pk'
```

Change `your_current_name_for_pk` with the current column name of your primary key of user table.